# Periodic solutions of $f^{(m)}=g$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $g:R \rightarrow R$ be continuous and $ 2\pi$-periodic, let $m \in N$. How many solution in  class of $m$-times continuously differentiable $2\pi$-periodic functions has equation $$f^{(m)}=g ?$$

Edit. Obviously, if $f$ is a solution in this class and $C$ is a constant then $f+C$ is also a solution. Are there another solutions?

Comment: More generally if $f$ is a solution and $p$ a polynomial of degree less than $m$ then $f + p$ is a solution, and conversely if $f_1, f_2$ are two solutions then $f_1 - f_2$ is a polynomial of degree less than $m$. So once you find a single solution (e.g. by the method below) you have all solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is $2\pi$-periodic then you can use Fourier series and write
$$
  g(x)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty g_ke^{i k x}
$$
and so also
$$
 f(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f_ke^{i k x}.
$$
By direct substitution you get
$$
    \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty (ik)^m f_k e^{i k x}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty g_k e^{i k x}
$$
then, all the solutions that can be cast in the form
$$
    (ik)^mf_k=g_k
$$
are periodic solutions of the given equation.